# cytoscape.js spread layout not showing anything

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I'm doing a small cytoscape.js project and was trying out the different layouts and see the results...

All the layouts I've tried work without issue, namely, cola, cose, cose-bilkent and dagre but spread does not (coincidentally it seems is the one I actually want to use...)

I get no errors on the console, only the following message: `Layout on 37 nodes took 78 ms`

Library versions:

- cytoscape.js: 2.7.8
- cytoscape.js-spread: 1.2.0

Does anyone have any idea why?